# Using SERVICE keyword in semantic web sparql query

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, endpoints

I'm trying to use [one of the SPARQL endpoints](http://cu.sider.bio2rdf.org/sparql) in order to run my query. Here is my query :

```
PREFIX  void:  <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#>
PREFIX    dv:  <http://bio2rdf.org/bio2rdf.dataset_vocabulary:>
SELECT DISTINCT ?sider_side_effect_ID3
 WHERE 
   {
     SERVICE <cu.sider.bio2rdf.org/sparql> 
       {
         ?sider_side_effect_ID3        <http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>                   ?sider_side_effect_label_ID3
       . ?sider_side_effect_label_ID3  bif:contains                                       "'Anxiety'"
       . ?sider_drug_ID2               a                                                  <http://bio2rdf.org/sider_vocabulary:Drug>
       . ?sider_drug_ID2               <http://bio2rdf.org/sider_vocabulary:side-effect>  ?sider_side_effect_ID3
   }   }
```

However, when I push the run button, I got the following error:

> `Virtuoso RDFZZ Error DB.DBA.SPARQL_REXEC('cu.sider.bio2rdf.org/sparql', ...) returned Content-Type 'text/html' status 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

If I remove the `SERVICE` keyword and its curly brackets, the query works fine. How could I use this keyword properly?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether it will fix your problem or not, but

```
SERVICE <cu.sider.bio2rdf.org/sparql> {
```

very well may need more of the URI components, e.g., `http://`:

```
SERVICE <http://cu.sider.bio2rdf.org/sparql> {
```